# Mutable object field within an Immutable class

Tags: java, immutability

I was assigned to create an immutable queue class in java and in that process what I did is actually had a private final arraylist, a startIndex, a lastIndex as fields. Eachtime I perform enqueue what I do is add the new value on top of the arraylist and return a new instance of class with a changed start and last index value. The dequeue operation also performs in a similar fashion. This way, after each enqueue/dequeue operation the new instance has its own start index, last index value of the array list while the previous instance holds its old value for those fields.

My question is that can I call this class immutable? Thank You.

Comment: Why don't you *show* us the code instead of describing it?

Comment: Sounds like bizzare implementation by the way

Comment: "Bizarre" is the best word for this.  I'd need a detailed specification of what an "immutable queue" actually does.  But off the top of my head, if you modify any fields (and you do modify the ArrayList) then your class is not immutable.

Comment: AFAIK immutable means that no matter what happens, the state of the object won't be modified, not even by calling methods of the class. From the moment you can enqueue or dequeue elements in your queue, it is not immutable at all.

Comment: The big problem with "immutable" in Java is that immutable objects are supposed to be thread safe.  ArrayList is not thread safe, so if you mutate it, you loose the immutable constraint.  And a more fundamental problem with the OP is relying on "tricky reasoning" to determine immutability.  Don't.  Do it the easy and obvious way.  Code maintainers will thank you.

Comment: It could be called effectively immutable though. If the underlying ArrayList is only added to, and startIndex/lastIndex are never modified. Then to users it would appear to be immutable. I haven't seen code but in theory you could do it. I am not advocating that this is actually immutable or that you should ever do it. I am just adding a viewpoint that it could appear to be immutable when it really isn't.

Comment: No it can't.  ArrayList might expand when you add one element.  It'll replace its entire internal array.  That's *way not immutable*.  You'll have huge problems in multi-threading.  Don't do this.

Comment: Is this one of these coding _exercises_ trying to understand functional languages by abusing non-functional languages? :-)

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions and comments. I myself even had seconds thought while trying to implement in this fashion. It seems I have so do some more study about immutability, thread safely and their effective uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the class is not immutable.

Basically, threads and the Java Memory Model are part of the language specification, so those parts of the language have to be considered whenever you ask about the behavior of a class.  Since `ArrayList` is not thread safe, and you mutate it, you cannot rely on that `ArrayList` to exhibit expected behavior, such as returning the first or last element in its array, in the presence of multiple threads.

The [Java Language Specification says:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)

> While most of the discussion in the preceding chapters is concerned
>   only with the behavior of code as executed a single statement or
>   expression at a time, that is, by a single thread, the Java Virtual
>   Machine can support many threads of execution at once. These threads
>   independently execute code that operates on values and objects
>   residing in a shared main memory...
>
> Threads are represented by the Thread class. The only way for a user
>   to create a thread is to create an object of this class; each thread
>   is associated with such an object. A thread will start when the
>   start() method is invoked on the corresponding Thread object.
>
> The behavior of threads, particularly when not correctly synchronized,
>   can be confusing and counterintuitive.

This is the money shot here, in [Section 17.4.5:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)

> More specifically, if two actions share a *happens-before* relationship,
>   they do not necessarily have to appear to have happened in that order
>   to any code with which they do not share a *happens-before*
>   relationship. Writes in one thread that are in a data race with reads
>   in another thread may, for example, appear to occur out of order to
>   those reads.

Since your `ArrayList` is not thread safe (no *happens-before* relationship) writes can occur in any order -- you may see the initial values when the internal array was initialized to nulls, some previous write, or the latest write.  One cannot tell.

So it is counter intuitive, because you *think* that if you have an index to the last element of an `ArrayList`, then that `ArrayList` will return the value of its last element, but the specification says "no."

Read that specification that I linked to, and get a copy of *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz.  That book is basically the bible of all things threads and Java.

Comment: Now I got the real picture for what I can not say my model immutable. Thank you. I will definitely try to have the copy of the book you suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

For immutability, the internal state of the queue's fields must never change as a result of enqueueing and dequeueing elements. One way to do this would be to create an entirely new instance of the queue and backing ArrayList each time. This will perform quite poorly in comparison to usual queue implementations, as both enqueue and dequeue operations will take O(n) time.

I am not sure what use this is, as usually queue's are assumed to change state - but perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
public class ImmutableQueue<T> {

    private final List<T> elements;

    public ImmutableQueue() {
        elements = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    private ImmutableQueue(List<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public ImmutableQueue<T> enqueue(T element) {
        List<T> copy = new ArrayList<T>(elements);
        copy.add(element);
        return new ImmutableQueue<T>(copy);
    }

    public DequeueResult dequeue() {
        if (elements.size() == 0) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        List<T> copy = new ArrayList<T>(elements);
        T head = copy.remove(0);
        return new DequeueResult(head, new ImmutableQueue<T>(copy));
    }

    public class DequeueResult {

        public final T element;
        public final ImmutableQueue<T> queue;

        public DequeueResult(T element, ImmutableQueue<T> queue) {
            this.element = element;
            this.queue = queue;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed implementation. I also actually tried to step back from this model because of the O(n) enqueue time. But now I see that if I do so I somehow deny the definition of immutable object which I can not afford for this assignment. Thank You again.

Comment: I found an alternative solution here, which uses a technique called structure sharing to achieve better performance: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/183766/how-to-increase-the-efficiency-of-an-immutable-queue-in-java